# How to plot a 3-D pointCloud object with Intensity information in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, point-clouds

I am using the MATLAB [`pointCloud`](https://mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pointcloud-class.html) class for working with and displaying 3-D point clouds. I have the coordinates of each point in *x*-, *y*-, and *z*-dimension, as well as a corresponding grayscale intensity value. For example, see the following test data:

```
x = [0,   1;   0,   1];
y = [0,   0;   1,   1];
z = [0,   0;   0,   0];
c = [0, 1/3; 2/3,   1];
```

The corresponding `pointCloud` object is created with

```
ptCloud = pointCloud(cat(3, x, y, z), 'Intensity', c);
```

Now I want to plot the point cloud using the [`pcshow`](https://mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcshow.html) command, i.e.

```
pcshow(ptCloud, 'MarkerSize', 1000);
```

*Note: the `'MarkerSize'` is only for this example, so the four points are clearly visible*.

This, however, doesn't take the intensity information into account - as stated in the documentation, this takes the color information of the point cloud object, which doesn't exist in my case.
The `pointCloud` object only allows to save RGB values for each pixel in the color field, i.e. grayscale intensities are not possible.

The  `pcshow` function can also take an `xyz` array and the corresponding color information as input instead of a `pointCloud` object. Then, using the grayscale intensity as color information is possible and works as expected:

```
pcshow(cat(3, x, y, z), c, 'MarkerSize', 1000);
```

However, I want to keep working with `pointCloud` objects and not fall back to multiple arrays per frame. How can I use the Intensity information of a `pointCloud` object in `pcshow`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recent MATLAB versions (at least R2018a) support this behavior out-of-the box. As described in the [documentation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcshow.html#buslb5n-1-ptCloud), for a point cloud object with Location and Intensity information, the intensity value is mapped to a color using the current color map.

So the following code snippet does work as expected in more recent MATLAB versions:

```
x = [0,   1;   0,   1];
y = [0,   0;   1,   1];
z = [0,   0;   0,   0];
c = [0, 1/3; 2/3,   1];

ptCloud = pointCloud(cat(3, x, y, z), 'Intensity', c);
pcshow(ptCloud, 'MarkerSize', 1000);
```

[image: resulting point cloud]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `repmat` on the 3rd dimension of `c` to create gray RGB color vectors, and then use `'Color'` property of `pointCloud`:

```
x = [0,   1;   0,   1];
y = [0,   0;   1,   1];
z = [0,   0;   0,   0];
c = [0, 1/3; 2/3,   1];
% convert grayscale intensities to gray rgb values
C = repmat(c,[1 1 3]);
% plot colored pointcloud
ptCloud = pointCloud(cat(3, x, y, z),'Color',C);
pcshow(ptCloud, 'MarkerSize', 1000);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem with this approach is that you can not use colormaps and the colorbar, so it is not really feasible in my case. I need to be able to set a colormap e.g. `colormap jet` and see the values corresponding to each color in a colorbar.

Comment: I see. And Setting the `'Color'` property using some colormap (`jet` for example) in advance will solve this?

Comment: Hm, not my favorite solution, but I guess that is a feasible work-around. It takes the flexibility of changing the colormap, but I guess one doesn't need that very often anyways.