# Is there any Octave's alternative to Matlab's pointCloud()?

Tags: matlab, octave

Is there any Octave's alternative to Matlab's pointCloud()?

Comment: How do know if Octave has this feature?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your attention.My code contains a pointCloud() function from matlab but when i want to run it in Octave it says : " error: 'pointCloud' undefined near line 74 column 11 "
also i dont know if there is any alternative for that in Octave, Just asking.

Comment: That wasn't my question. You're getting an undefined error because it doesn't exist. My question is how do you know a equivalent function exists in Octave?

Comment: I said i dont know if there is any alternative function for that in Octave. Sorry for my late edit of my comment.

Comment: You're just editing your question so it appears on the front page :) But I'm unaware of Octave doing any cloud computing.

Comment: Thank you in advance. But i think pointCloud() is not for cloud computing. i used it in matlab just for creating 3-D dotted graph which apparently doesn't work in Octave.

Comment: @KingDuken, for an example of the use of pointCloud, see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43898012/how-to-plot-a-3-d-pointcloud-object-with-intensity-information-in-matlab

Comment: Make a feature request for it on the Octave bug tracker! https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/octave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the short answer is No. Octave has only recently implemented a fairly robust equivalent of classdef, so many of the Matlab classes, that have been introduced in the past few years, including PointCloud, have not yet been implemented.

Comment: Recently? I haven't checked but I think it's more than 5 years ago

Comment: In think the first renditions of classdef came with 4.4(?) but it was still pretty limited. I think it got better with 5.1 but is still unable to do everything needed to fully emulate MATLAB classes.

Comment: Yep. The short answer is "No"; the longer answer is "No, but please come over to the Octave bug tracker and make a feature request for it!" https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/octave